# display specific details related to id using volley

Tags: php, android, json, url, android-volley

I am dynamically loading buttons in 1 activity and onClick() event of the button next activity is loaded. In the below activity I want to display details related to the buttons i.e if user clicks QUEST it should display only QUEST details and if user clicks SRL it should display only SRL details. I am unable to get. Can anyone help?

```
public void loadDescriptionList() {
    String url = "https://diagnostic.hisaabwaale.in/AndroidAppController/testGet";
    final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(TestDetails.this);
    progressDialog.setMessage("Loading Data...");
    progressDialog.show();
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    try {
                        obj = new JSONObject(response);
                        heroArray = obj.getJSONArray("list");
                        for (int i = 0; i < heroArray.length(); i++) {
                            heroObject = heroArray.getJSONObject(i);
                            TDescription hero = new TDescription(heroObject.getString("test_code"), heroObject.getString("test_description"), heroObject.getString("test_price"));
                            heroList.add(hero);
                        }
                        adapter = new ListViewAdapter(heroList, getApplicationContext());
                        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Records Found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Records Found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("franchise", franchise);
            return params;
        }
    };
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

Backend api

```
  function testGet(){
  $response = array();
  $franchise = $this->input->post('franchise');
  $result = $this->testModel->testlist($franchise);
  if($result != 0){
    $response['status'] = 200;
    $response['list'] = $result;
  }else{
    $response['status'] = 201;
    $response['msg'] = 'No Records';
  }
  echo json_encode($response);
}
```

this is the model

```
public function testlist($franchise)
{
    $query = "SELECT t.id, t.franchise_id, t.test_code, t.test_description, t.test_price
            FROM `".$this->table."` as t
            WHERE t.franchise_id = ".$franchise;
   $result = $this->db->query($query);
   if($result->num_rows() > 0){
     return $result->result();
   }else{
     return 0;
   }
```

}

**LOGCAT**

```
12-22 00:24:34.459 22632-22632/hisaabwaale.in.hisaabwaale E/MultiWindowProxy: getServiceInstance failed!
```

12-22 00:24:37.574 22632-22632/? E/MultiWindowProxy: getServiceInstance failed!
12-22 00:24:37.696 22632-22632/? E/MultiWindowProxy: getServiceInstance failed!
12-22 00:24:38.637 22632-22863/? E/NativeCrypto: ssl=0xacc22880 cert_verify_callback x509_store_ctx=0x9f0f9e4c arg=0x0
12-22 00:24:38.637 22632-22863/? E/NativeCrypto: ssl=0xacc22880 cert_verify_callback calling verifyCertificateChain authMethod=ECDHE_RSA
12-22 00:24:40.080 22632-22664/? E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xa0921dc0
12-22 00:24:40.111 22632-22632/? E/Error: Failedorg.json.JSONException: Index 2 out of range [0..2)
12-22 00:24:40.255 22632-22664/? E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xa0921640
12-22 00:24:55.343 22632-22632/? E/MultiWindowProxy: getServiceInstance failed!
12-22 00:24:55.452 22632-23164/? E/Volley: [125517] NetworkDispatcher.run: Unhandled exception java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.length()' on a null object reference
                                           java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.length()' on a null object reference
                                               at libcore.net.UriCodec.encode(UriCodec.java:132)
                                               at java.net.URLEncoder.encode(URLEncoder.java:57)
                                               at com.android.volley.Request.encodeParameters(Request.java:484)
                                               at com.android.volley.Request.getBody(Request.java:470)
                                               at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.addBodyIfExists(HurlStack.java:253)
                                               at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.setConnectionParametersForRequest(HurlStack.java:227)
                                               at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.performRequest(HurlStack.java:107)
                                               at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:97)
                                               at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:114)
12-22 00:24:55.742 22632-22664/? E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xa0921aa0

Comment: Well what's the ID for QUEST and SRL? I tested your API on Postman and I get a response 500 response back if I send SRL or QUEST. If I send an integer I get `{"status":201,"msg":"No Records"}` I'm not familiar with PHP, but your Java code looks fine. On either QUEST / SRL button click have `franchise = the_right_ID` and I don't see why you shouldn't get a response back.

Comment: @Stephen Lightcap : The app is showing no records to display. The id's are 8 and 12

Comment: @Aparana can you print the Volley Error in `onErrorResponse`?

Comment: @Aparana if it's getting a response correctly and not error, print the response as is. Troubleshoot and narrow down where the error is. It might be the `JSONException` getting thrown and saying there's no records.

Comment: Ah, Null. Try `JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);` unless you declared it out of scope already.

Answer (score 0):

```
Button QUEST= (Button) findViewById(R.id.QUEST);
QUEST.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
       Intent mIntent = new Intent(this, Example.class);
       Bundle extras = mIntent.getExtras();
       extras.putString('franchise', '8'); 

    }
});

Button SRL= (Button) findViewById(R.id.SRL);
SRL.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //Same as other, just different franchise
    }
});
```

When you open up the next activity:

```
String franchise = getIntent().getExtras().getString(franchise)
```

Then call `loadDescriptionList()` Maybe have it take a string? Like

`loadDescriptionList(String franchise)` and when you open the new activity:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    loadDescriptionList(getIntent().getExtras().getString(franchise))
}
```

I'm assuming `loadDescriptionList()` is on the next activity called. Hope this helps or steers you in the correct direction.

**EDIT**

You can also use `Bundle` like below to pass values to next activity:

```
Intent mIntent = new Intent(this, Example.class);
Bundle mBundle = new Bundle();
mBundle.putString(key, value);
mIntent.putExtras(mBundle);
```

Comment: But I am creating buttons dynamically so I dont know in future if there wud be more buttons. Now I have just 2. so wud it work that way?

Comment: Yes, you can add the click listener when you're looping through the creation of the buttons. [Check this out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44680170/adding-a-different-putextra-to-an-intent-for-each-dynamically-created-button)

Comment: I tried what you suggested but only last id present in db is getting displayed.